# How to Submit Jobs without a Cluster

Tags: ubuntu

This is probably a simple question. I just set up a ubuntu configured server with 36 TB which will be used for less than a dozen people. In my previous jobs, I have been using LSF cluster servers and they all had ways to submit jobs such as qsub and bsub.

However, this server is not a cluster. I am wondering if there is some software or tools I can install to submit jobs so that they run overnight, and I can shut down my interactive session. I tried a number of commands, such as adding & or &! at the end of my jobs to run them in the background, but the jobs fail after I close my interactive session. If anyone knows of a simple program that will allow us to submit jobs on a single server, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You should use nohup. It is a command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. So, if you want to start a job, logout and let the job continue, you should use the following:

```
$ nohup a_job &
```

You should note that if that process receives i/o (stdin, stdout, stderr) it might hangup. To overcome this, you should redirect i/o:

```
$ nohup a_job > outfile 2> errorfile < /dev/null &
```

An alternative to using nohup, may be using a terminal multiplexer like screen or tmux.

Comment: I will second the suggestion for screen.